# title in table header should not repeat in foreach loop in laravel

Tags: html, laravel, foreach

My view

```
<table class="table">
  @foreach($students as $student)
    <thead>
      <tr style="background-color: #e9e5e4;">
        <td colspan="4">{{$student->teacher_name}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th> Name </th>
        <th> class</th>
        <th> subject </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> {{$student->name }}</td>
        <td> {{$student->class}} </td>
        <td> {{$student->subject }} </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    @endforeach
  </table>
```

it shows me multiple tables even when teacher name is same , I just want to make new table only when teacher name is changed else show all record in same table

Comment: What does your data look like? Might be easier to adjust your query to group by the teacher and use two loops to construct the table

Answer (score 0):

You placed your loop wrong. Try this

```
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
        @foreach($students as $student)
          <tr style="background-color: #e9e5e4;">
            <td colspan="4">{{$student->teacher_name}}</td>
          </tr>
         @endforeach
          <tr>
            <th> Name </th>
            <th> class</th>
            <th> subject </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($students as $student)
          <tr>
            <td> {{$student->name }}</td>
            <td> {{$student->class}} </td>
            <td> {{$student->subject }} </td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: in this way title is showing multipe times on top . but i want title on all table separately

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Class</th>
    <th>Subject</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  @foreach($students as $student)
    <tr style="background-color: #e9e5e4;">
      <td colspan="4">{{$student->teacher_name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>{{$student->name }}</td>
      <td>{{$student->class}} </td>
      <td>{{$student->subject }} </td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

***OR***

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Class</th>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Teacher</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  @foreach($students as $student)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$student->name }}</td>
      <td>{{$student->class}} </td>
      <td>{{$student->subject }} </td>
      <td style="background-color: #e9e5e4;">{{$student->teacher_name}}</td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```